# Is there another posibility to restart a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read it is not possible to restart the same `Thread`. If it should be restarted, then you have to create a new `Thread`.

But the thing is, the threads are limited, you can not create 40,000 threads because the operating system can only create 15,000 threads. (This is just an example).

Is there another possibility?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use code font for words that aren't code.

Comment: "Is there another possibility" for what? Are you trying to *run* 40,000 threads simultaneously? Why? Or, do you have 40,000 tasks you need to run, but not at the same time? It's not clear what your issue is or why you think restarting threads would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the thing is, the threads are limited, you can not create 40,000 threads because the operating system can only create 15,000 threads. (This is just an example).

Yes, that's confusing - but you're mixing terms.

A java `java.lang.Thread` object **is not an OS-level thead**.

You can make a million or so Thread objects. Go ahead, try it.

You would not be able to simultaneously start all 1 million of em, however - `start()` causes things to occur, eventually leading to an 'OS level thread' to be created.

Once a thread ends, the `java.lang.Thread` object will stick around, but the OS level thread won't. Hence, your central problem thesis, which I'll summarize as:

> Restarting an existing java.lang.Thread object is better than creating a new java.lang.Thread object, because I read that you can only have 40k or so java.lang.Thread objects

Is just flat out wrong. There is zero benefit between a hypothetical re-use of a j.l.Thread object by 'restarting' it (which implies it has ended), vs. just making a new object instead once the 'old' one has ended.

What you'd have to do if you want to 'restart' a thread is to have a `run()` method (the one that the thread ends up running in a new thread) that is a frameworky thing: It checks a queue of jobs, pulls one queue off the top, runs it, and then goes back to checking the queue. This is tantamount to 'reusing a thread', though you're now just reinventing what [`ExecutorPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) (baked into core java itself) and friends already do.

ExecutorPools are probably a good idea. However, they don't 'solve' your problem. Your problem isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Executor` or `ExecutorService`. Class `Executors` has some factory methods for those. By using one that uses a thread pool you can submit actions without threads necessarily being created for each separate action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). Database connections are often managed in a thread pool, for example. After it has done its work (e.g., queried some data), the thread returns to the pool, and can be reused.

The other thing you may be missing is: while you cannot have e.g., 40,000 threads at a time, nothing prevents you from creating new threads after old ones have finished.